# QProcess stateChanged signal not emitted correctly

Tags: qt, qprocess

I want to write a simple application (i.e. starter) that starts my main application and further monitors its state and restarts it, if it crashes/exits.

Its very simple. I use the `QProcess` for this purpose and run the main application (app1) and handle its `stateChanged` signal.

To test it, i have written a very small console app that would print out its name and then just return via `exit(-1)` (simulating the case where the program has exited for some reason).

Everything goes as expected for the first time and the `stateChanged` signal is emmited in every stage. App1 would immediately exit after its launch, again causing the `staeChanged` signal to be emitted for the 2nd time.

The problem is that after APP1 is launced for the 2nd time (and consequently exited) the `stateChanged` signal is not emmited anymore !!!

What have i done wrong? Should i re-connect the signals each each time i start the application via QProcess OR ...???

Note: I see this case both under windows and linux.

```
starter::starter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_process = new QProcess(this);
    m_process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ProcessChannelMode::ForwardedChannels);
    connect(m_process, &QProcess::stateChanged, this, &starter::onStateChanged);

    m_process->setProgram("myapp1");
    m_process->setArguments(QStringList());

    startProcess();
}

void starter::onStateChanged(const QProcess::ProcessState &state)
{
    qDebug() << "state changed to : " << state;

    if(state == QProcess::ProcessState::NotRunning){
        this->startProcess();
    }
}


void starter::startProcess()
{
    qDebug() << "start process App1";
    m_process->start();
    if(m_process->waitForStarted(1000)){
        qDebug() << "[+] App started";
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "[!] Failed to start app";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
C:\myapp1-release>starter.exe
start process : "myapp1"
state changed to :  QProcess::Starting
state changed to :  QProcess::Running
[+] App started
state changed to :  QProcess::NotRunning
start process : "myapp1"
state changed to :  QProcess::Starting
state changed to :  QProcess::Running
[+] App started

*NO FURTHER REACTION TO THE EXIT OF APP1*
```

Comment: remove `waitForStarted`

Comment: I removed the ``waitForStarted`` and it did not help. The same problem persists (app1 emits the signal only 2 times).

Comment: terminate process at end "m_process->terminate();"

Comment: What do you mean by "end"? I put ``m_process->terminate()`` at ``onStateChanged`` when application not running is sensed.
But it did not help. My real program switches between 2 apps (based on user request) and uses ``terminate()`` for this. In this case i have no problem and i get the signals every time i close the apps). **The problem is seen when the app is killed manually or crashes/exits by itself.**

Comment: Further Observation: If i make the sample "myapp1" to not exit and block on ``app.exec()`` and instead kill it manually (e.g. kill -9 pid) the same problem is observed (i.e. the ``stateChanged`` signal is emmited only the first time the app1 is killed manually)

Answer (score 0):

My (not so good) solution:
I delete the old QProcess object and instantiate it again when i detect an application crash/exit.

This way the signal is emmited for all other and consequent app's crashes/exits.

```
m_process->deleteLater();//delete the old instance - I hope its signal/slot connections are cleared automatically by Qt ??!!
m_process = new QProcess(this);
m_process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ProcessChannelMode::ForwardedChannels);
connect(m_process, &QProcess::stateChanged, this, &starter::onStateChanged);//make connections for the new instance
```

The hint to take this approach came from Qt's documentation for QProcess::close():

> Closes all communication with the process and kills it. **After
> calling this function, QProcess will no longer emit readyRead(), and
> data can no longer be read or written.**

Has Qt's documentation missed to mention that if qprocess application exits or gets killed manually the `stateChanged` signal will not be emitted any more? Or probably i am missing sth.

Any comment on the correctness of this approach is highly appreciated.